# Magento 1.9.1 - Element with id "bureauid" already exists

Tags: admin, customer, ce-1.9.1.0

When I go in the section Customer > Manage customers > Click on a customer, this error :

```
Element with id "bureauid" already exists
```

This error since I installed magento 1.8 to 1.9.1.

Answer (score 2):

This is a custom extension problem and pretty off-topic since you have not provided any info, but here's something you could try.

1. Do a string search for `'bureauid'` in your entire `app/code` directory.
2. Locate where you're adding this twice, possibly via the method `addColumn()` in a `Form.php` file.
3. Don't add this column more than once.

Answer (score 1):

bureauid seems to come from an extension that is probably to be updated to work with 1.9.1 and I tend to believe that an ID in the datatable is not really correct but it is difficult to say just like that.